# Как переназначить title и placeholder для поля email в django-allauth

Tags: python, django, ооп

Я использую django-allauth в django проекте для аутентификации на сайте. В шаблоны поля заполняются django-crispy-forms. Я нашел как переопределить заголовок и заполнитель для поля пароль, но как переопределить эти строки для поля e-mail не могу разобраться..

```
forms.py
...
class LoginForm(forms.Form):

# переопределяя этот атрибут изменяется как заголовок поля, так и заполнитель.  
    password = PasswordField(label=_("custom_name_for_label_Pass))
```

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py

Для аутентификации использую метод с e-mail.

Подскажите плиз как найти решение! Заранее спасибо за помощ!

Comment: аналогично, думаю

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 всё верно

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, не обратил внимание на присвоение атрибута login_field.

```
your_app/forms.py

from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm, PasswordField

class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):

    password = PasswordField(label="Пароль ")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        login_widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'email',
                                                'placeholder':
                                                ('введите адрес эл.почты'),
                                                'autofocus': 'autofocus'})
        login_field = forms.EmailField(label=("Почта"),
                                        widget=login_widget)

        self.fields["login"] = login_field #не обратил внимание на это переопределение
```